# How to list RDDs defined in Spark shell?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In both "spark-shell" or "pyspark" shells, I created many RDDs but I could not find any way through which I can list all the available RDDs in my current session of Spark Shell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python you can simply try to filter `globals` by type:

```py
def list_rdds():
    from pyspark import RDD
    return [k for (k, v) in globals().items() if isinstance(v, RDD)]

list_rdds()
# []

rdd = sc.parallelize([])
list_rdds()
# ['rdd']
```

In Scala REPL you should be able to use `$intp.definedTerms` / `$intp.typeOfTerm` in a similar way.

Comment: RE: scala REPL:  works great: nice tip. Now how do I remember those commands .. ;)

Comment: Can you post a solution @javadba? Perhaps expand on @zero323's answer.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I've tried something like [this](https://gist.github.com/zero323/9da96f5c319c678ceef8) and it kind of works but it is far to hacky (not to mention shows my complete lack of understanding of Scala compiler) to make it an answer.

Comment: I am not going to downvote, but this will only work on rdds that are defined in the global scope. If you have rdds created in a function (e.g. a helper function), it will not be on the global scope.