# How can one see what RDD is available to Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I just started to use Spark. I try to follow [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) tutorial (I use Python).

As the first two sentences I see the following:

> Spark’s primary abstraction is a distributed collection of items
>   called a Resilient Distributed Dataset (RDD). RDDs can be created from
>   Hadoop InputFormats (such as HDFS files) or by transforming other
>   RDDs. Let’s make a new RDD from the text of the README file in the
>   Spark source directory

As far as I understood it correctly, Spark has "access" to items that are distributed over different machines belonging to a cluster on which Spark is running. These items can be imagined as files (or at least as something that can be obtained from a file). In particular, by executing the following:

```
textFile = sc.textFile("test.txt")
```

we use "test.txt" file to create a new "item" and to add it to the set of items that are visible (accessible) by Spark.

Did I get it right. If it is the case, how can I see all the "items" available to the Spark. In particular, how can I see that a newly created item is there.

**ADDED**

To one of the users it was not clear what I mean. So, I try to clarify. In the tutorial a "distributed collection of items" is mentioned. So, there are some "items". Can one see what items exists? Or at least how many items exist? Can I type something in the PySpark session to get a number of existing "items"?

I also have a problem with the terminology. Is it a set of items that is called RDD or each element (item) in the set is called RDD (the sentence that I refer to is ambiguous in this respect). By executing `sc.textFile` we made a new RDD. So, we added an item to the set of items? Can we see the items in the set (or at least the number of items in the set).

**ADDED 2**

It looks like that it is still not clear what I mean. I do not understand what is not clear. Maybe those for whom my question is not clear could specify more details about what exactly is unclear.

But anyway, I try more.

> Spark’s primary abstraction is a distributed collection of items
>   called a Resilient Distributed Dataset (RDD).

If there is a collection of items, there should be a way to get some information about this "collection of items". For example, it is natural to assume that a collection of items can be characterized by number of items in the collection. Can I get this number?

Comment: I'm not the "same user" you mentioned in your update, but it's still not clear.

Comment: `wholeTextFiles` returns both the content and the file name if that is what you want.

Comment: RDD is just a object like any other. It has no special meaning.

Comment: @zero323, but can we count these objects?

Comment: [How to know list of RDD available in Spark shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33840087/1560062).

Answer (score 0):

Spark can read every file/directory both on local filesystem and on HDFS or other distributed filesystem as S3.

When you write `sc.textFile` you are creating a RDD from the contents of the file/directory you specify. In particoular, each line of the file/directory becomes an entry of the RDD.

An RDD is a **collection** of items. It's the acronym of Resilient Distributed Dataset, i.e. it is a collection of items distribute among the nodes of the cluster.

For instance, if you have the file `test.txt` stored on HDFS in the directory `/tmp` and it contains the rows:

```
one
two
three
```

by writing `sc.textFile('hdfs://tmp/test.txt')` you create a RDD which contains three strings (one for each line).

Hope my explaination is enough. If you need more details just ask.

Answer (score 0):

> These items can be imagined as files (or at least as something that can be obtained from a file).

Not really. I guess a fundamental problem here is understanding a relation between RDD and the actual data. It is important to note following facts:

- RDDs are lazily evaluated. If there is no action executed on a given RDD it won't be materialized.
- RDDs are a description and don't really contain the data.

There are some subtleties involved, for example when you parallelize a local data structure and data is captured inside a closure, but it doesn't really affect this answer.

When you call:

```
textFile = sc.textFile("test.txt")
```

nothing really happens.

Well, it creates a Python object and a corresponding Java object but at this point a file may not even exist. Once again there are situation when things get more complicated, especially with `DataFrames`, where Spark may access some metadata or even read a whole dataset to infer schema, but lets stick to the basics.

Unless RDD has been cached and materialized there is no persistent distributed state transparent to user, so there is nothing to list beyond local variables.