# \List all DataFrames in Spark's current session/memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 10s of DFs in PySpark assigned to different variable names such as:
`var1 = DF1`, `var2 = DF2`, etc.
Is there a built-in function in Spark/PySpark to list all DFs in memory/session? or any other way around?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can adjust [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33845361/8371915) from [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33845361/8371915):

```
def list_dataframes():
    from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
    return [k for (k, v) in globals().items() if isinstance(v, DataFrame)]
```

If object is registered then catalog will help:

```
spark = ...  # SparkSession

spark.catalog.listTables()
```

Comment: made some editions based on my context. Worked well. Thanks.